# Replacing Itext with PDFbox and boxable

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, pdfbox, boxable

Iam replacing iText jar with PDFbox and boxable jar and certain classes on iText are not available in PDFbox. Is there any alternate way to replace the chunk class in iText into PDFbox .

Comment: Welcome to SO. While many people can understand your migration step both libraries are completely different and do not share any root. So a "migration" will be basically a new implementation since  you can not just replace some Classnames or methods. So you better do not ask what to replace Chunk.java with but what you are trying to do (e.g. I want to create a PDF and add text to it ...) And then users can help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.